# How to do delta extraction from GIT for patching?

Tags: git, patch, delta

I am new to GIT and we just started working on a MobApp

How to perform a delta level extraction from GIT (provided 'tags' were created for each change) ?

Please let me know the various ways to accomplish this

Thanks
Sathish Kumar

Comment: What do you call a "delta level extraction?"

Answer (score 1):

To create individual patches for all the commits since `abc`, simply do `git format-patch abc`. This will create one patch file per commit. If you just want to see what has changed since `abc`, do `git diff abc HEAD`.